# Desktop does not shown in gnome's file manager sidebar

Tags: gnome, gnome-session-fallback

I'm using gnome fallback on  Ubuntu 20.04 and have the pesky issue that I can not see the `Desktop` on the left sidebar below `Home`:

[image]

This makes navigation unnecessarily awkward. So I'm wondering if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the entry for Desktop in your ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs configuration file looks like:

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
```

Comment: It is like this: `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
`